# Create PostgreSQL fulltext Parser

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, parse

I want to make a FTS on my text column on Postgres, the problem is that I want to search words with "_" between letters, like "the_event" but the default parser split those words and identify "_" like a blank space. If I debug the parser I get the following:

```
postgres=> SELECT ts_parse('default', 'the_event');
 ts_parse
-----------
 (1,the)
 (12,_)
 (1,event)
(3 rows)
```

More specifically, I want to create a FTS parser that doesn't split a word with certain characters. How can I create a parser on Postgres?

Comment: I think you need to write your own in C: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtsparser.html

Comment: I had read that page, but I haven't found an example for the parameters yet ):

Comment: There is https://github.com/postgrespro/tsexample and https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2019/03/28/tsearch-dictionary.html - I don't know if they are idiomatic or not - but perhaps it's a start.